# Animating a button that fills up with a color

Tags: android, animation, button

In need to create an animation. the animation is a color that fills a button according to the percentage that is given.
that's how is should look:
[image]

As you see, the yellow color is filling up 44% of the button.
How can I do this with animation so that it starts "empty" and ends like the image I uploaded?
Thanks!

Comment: Is it [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) you are looking for?

Comment: Its not an indicator of a download or something, its just a presentation of information. I am asking about how to create the animation itself.  should I use scale animation with a transparent button or any other suggestion?